# Magento 2 - Move block or container only for specific Device

Tags: magento2, xml

Is it possible to move block or container in Magento 2 only for specific device?

For example, I want to move minicart like that

`<move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" before="-"/>`

but this code should apply only for Desktop and Table device. But not for Mobile device.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use different themes and "User-Agent Exceptions" functionality.

Comment: Isn't user agent the browser not necessarily the device?