# Move block in Magento 2 without xml

Tags: magento2

Can anybody tell how to move block in Magento2 using observer or maybe other class without using "move" tag in layout xml.

I know about this method in layout, but I can not use it.

```
<move element="name" destination="to" before="-"/>
```

In my case "move" depends on 2 store config values.

And YES, I saw this: [Magento 2 - Move block or container only for specific Device](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126654/magento-2-move-block-or-container-only-for-specific-device)

Thank

Answer (score 4):

In your observer, check if the conditions for moving the block are met. if so, get the layout and manually add a layout update within the observer.

Here's an example that uses an observer on `layout_load_before`:

```
namespace Company\Module\Observer;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * add custom layout updates
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $move = false;

        // add your checks here

        if ($move) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout */
            $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
            $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<move element="blah" destination="to" before="-" />');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

this event conveniently provides access to the layout. if you are stuck with a specific event, there are other ways to access the current layout to add the update.